# EventKit updating/deleting events: strange intermittent problems

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, eventkit

I am fetching EventKit `EKEvent` instances with `[EKEventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:]`. I then either delete them (by using `[EKEventStore removeEvent:span:error:]`) or modify them (by setting various properties and using `[EKEVentStore saveEvent:span:error:]`). I am trying to keep my app compatible with iOS4.3, so I'm not using the newer methods with the "commit" mechanism.

Both `saveEvent` and `removeEvent` return `YES` when I call them. Still, for some reason, I am seeing some really bizzare behaviour (on a physical iPhone 4 / iOS4.3.3 device):

- When moving an event from one calendar to another (setting `EKEvent.calendar` and then calling `saveEvent`), the event ends up in both calendars! (This happens every time or nearly every time).
- When deleting an event, the event sometimes does not actually get deleted (verified through the native Calendar app), even though `removeEvent` returns `YES`. This is an intermittent problem, happens about 10% of the time.
- When changing event title (setting `EKEvent.title` and then calling `saveEvent`), the event sometimes does not actually get deleted, even though `saveEvent` returns `YES`. This too is highly intermittent, though seems to happen more often than the deletion problem.

How can I ensure my events are properly deleted/updated?

Comment: Also, it seems that there's sometimes a delay before the strange behavior above takes effect... Seems like some sort of synchronization issue.

Comment: One more piece of information: The calendars are all synced to Google Calendars. I am beginning to suspect that this is at the root of some of these problems.